# How to write a python script to send email notification

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

```
try:
elem = rd.driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Entries feed')
if elem.is_displayed():
    elem.click()
    print("Login is successful")
```

except NoSuchElementException:
print("Login is Unsuccessful, element cannot be found")

I want to write a code that sends an email when one of the messages is displayed.

Comment: there are plenty of tutorials for that, what did you try?

Comment: I am quite new to python, I have tried different ones but no avail. My plan is actually to output whatever the console output shows to an external text file, and then probably attach and send it as a mail.